# Kivy: Function Call to Update Label Text in Another Class Not Working

Tags: python, kivy, label, kivy-language

I have a class called `StatSummary` that has labels and a button at the bottom called "Reset". When I press this button, a popup appears with a button that also says "Reset". When I press the popup "Reset" button, I want to update the labels' text of the class `StatSummary`. I created a method inside `StatSummary` called `resetStatSummary` which updates the labels' text using IDs.

However, when I call `Factory.StatSummary().resetStatSummary()` from `ResetPopup`, the labels on the screen do not update. This is especially confusing because I added a print statement in my Python file to see if the function runs and it does, but the labels' text does not update.

Python File:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class StatSummary(Screen):
    def resetStatSummary(self):  # resets StatSummary text when "Reset" button is pressed
        self.ids.summaryShotFractionLabel.text = "0/0"
        self.ids.summaryShotPercentLabel.text = "0.0%"
        self.ids.summaryLongStreakLabel.text = "Longest Streak: 0"
        print("resetStatSummary ran")

class ResetPopup(Popup):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file('basketball.kv')

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

.kv File:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

WindowManager:        
    StatSummary

<StatSummary>
    name: "statSummary"        
    GridLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"

            Label:
                id: summaryShotFractionLabel
                text: "0/0"
                
            Label:
                id: summaryShotPercentLabel
                text: "0.0%"
                
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Label:
                id: summaryLongStreakLabel
                text: "Longest Streak: 0"                    

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"            
        Button:
            text: "Reset"
            on_release:
                Factory.ResetPopup().open()

<ResetPopup>:
title: "Wait..."
BoxLayout:
    cols: 1
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: "Are you sure you want to reset?"

    Button:
        text: "Go back"
        on_release:
            root.dismiss()

    Button:
        text: "Reset"
        on_release:
            root.dismiss()
            Factory.StatSummary().resetStatSummary()
            app.root.current = "interact"
            app.root.transition.direction = "right"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label doesn't change because you call wrong object's `resetStatSummary` method.

Within reset's `on_release` button method you have:

```
Factory.StatSummary().resetStatSummary()
```

which means: create fresh new `StatSummary` object (`StatSummary()` will create and return new object - class `StatSummary` instance), then call it's method `resetStatSummary()`. So you call this method on brand new object, not this created by kv file. To access expected StatSummary class instance just replace line:

```
Factory.StatSummary().resetStatSummary()
```

with

```
app.root.get_screen('statSummary').resetStatSummary()
```